# In IE higher versions(IE 8 +) the background -color is not coming while giving print.I want to force print using CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, background-color

In IE, the background-color is not getting print.I want to force print background color without selecting the "print background color" option in browsers.I tried using background property.It is not working.Filter property was working fine in IE8. But in higher versions of IE it is not working.ALL other browsers chrome, safari,Firefox box-shadow will do the job.Please let me know any other CSS alternative for IE8 + versions.

Comment: I've had some success with using borders. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/rby4bwnd/ (The first div has a normal background, the second uses the border trick. See print preview for difference.) But that works only if you know exactly how high your content is.

Comment: Or only the output pane (since IE8 doesn't handle JSfiddle's frameset well) http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/rby4bwnd/show